# add jsdoc for javascript core in intellij

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, jsdoc

I am new to IntelliJ Idea
I want to add jsdoc for JavaScript core
That means, when I press the ctrl+q short key on a javascript element like **.getElementsByTagName()** method , I want to see the documentation, but there is not any thing!

Is there any way?
Like adding documentation jar file near to a library jar file for showing documentation.

Thanks
Mohi

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is taken from the `DOMCore.js` stub file that doesn't contain a lot of useful information:

[image: DomCore.js]

If you know where to find or how to generate similar stub file with complete documentation, it should be possible to use it instead.